# How to get all instance that does not have a specific Tag using Python in MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services

I am trying to get a list of instance name which don't have a specific Tag. (NoAlarms).

Here is what I am using now:

```
lst_instances = GetListRDSIdentifiers(accesskey, secretkey)
lst_expected_alarms = []
for inst in lst_instances:
    if "relprac" not in inst.lower() 
do xxxxx
```

Now I want to add another condition which if select all instances that do not have tag "NoAlarms" in it. How do I achieve that? I know it's probably just add something like

```
for tags in 1st_instances:
 if "NoAlarms" not in tags.tags
```

But I am not sure how to do it. We are using RDS not EC2.

How can I fix this?

Comment: the error tells your that the `inst` variable inside your `for` loop is a string, rather than anything else you expect it to be, meaning that the `GetListRDSIdentifiers` call returns you a list of strings (or at least one element in the list is string)

Comment: @iulian Hi, I understand what you were saying so I edit my question now. I still can't get what I need.